# RavenDB Query does not return all records

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am trying to get back all of the objects which I have saved in the database but not all of them come back:

```
var everything = session.Query<MyObject>()
                        .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted &&
                                     x.WorkflowStatus == WorkflowStatus.Published);
```

I have 206 objects in total, a good 80% of them fit the criteria above but only 127 are returned.

Can anyone see why?

Comment: too specific without any generic information on classes, queries,...

Comment: The question is not vague at all. If you know Raven, it's a simple answer.

Comment: Thank you for backing me up Diego.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, [queries return up to 128 records](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/basic-operations/basic-querying?version=2.0).

Use an explicit `Take(n)` to get more records.

Comment: Thank you very much Diego!. Is there a way to set this by default on DocumentSession so that I don't need to explicitly specify Take(n)?

Comment: Not that I know. This is intentional.